# Где взять crystal для arm64?

Tags: arm, crystal

Такой вопрос: где взять crystal для arm64. Дело в том, что нету deb пакетов под arm64. Собрать из исходников - там нужен уже имеющийся crystal... Получается вопрос курицы и яйца... И это тебе не gcc/clang/binutils, который можно спокойно компилировать на другую платформу, а готовый есть везде...

Пытаюсь собрать в Kali Nethunter.